# Default Site Icons have disappeared 

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, file-icons

I dont know what is wrong with site icons. All icons images are gone, when I see their properties, the path is fine, image is located on that path, but image of that icon is not being appearing at all.

Comment: Are your alternate access mappings correct for the web app?

Answer (score 1):

Are the files checked in, published, and approved?